# debugging Android apps?

Tags: android, debugging

I am now trying to improve my programming skills and specially I would like to now how you debug those situations where the app lags a bit. I tried to move most of the critical parts to threads but still I get some ANR. I guess my app is leaking memory somewhere.

So, how to debug this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should spend some time reading this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

From **Strict Mode** reference page:

> StrictMode is most commonly used to
>   catch accidental disk or network
>   access on the application's main
>   thread, where UI operations are
>   received and animations take place.
>   Keeping disk and network operations
>   off the main thread makes for much
>   smoother, more responsive
>   applications. By keeping your
>   application's main thread responsive,
>   you also prevent ANR dialogs  from
>   being shown to users.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)
It's now even included in the eclipse android dev tools plugin.