# Android finding a deadlock

Tags: android, deadlock

I am getting an ANR sometimes when I run my Android service. I suspect it is happening because of a deadlock.

Is there an easy way to monitor deadlock in Android or Eclipse. Such as a utility to show which thread hold which lock etc.?

And is there a way to figure out a deadlock by looking at traces.txt file?

My ddms log looks like this at the time of crash

```
02-15 18:09:01.046: INFO/Process(90): Sending signal. PID: 450 SIG: 3
02-15 18:09:01.046: INFO/dalvikvm(450): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-15 18:09:01.056: INFO/dalvikvm(450): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-15 18:09:01.076: INFO/Process(90): Sending signal. PID: 10548 SIG: 9
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90): ANR in com.abc.cm.core
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90): Reason: Executing service com.abc.cm.core/.WorkOrderManager
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90): Load: 1.46 / 1.16 / 1.05
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90): CPU usage from 19462ms to 1067ms ago:
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   abc.cm.core: 13% = 12% user + 1% kernel / faults: 1360 minor
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   mmcqd: 4% = 0% user + 4% kernel
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   system_server: 3% = 2% user + 1% kernel / faults: 473 minor
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   zygote: 2% = 2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 90 minor
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   adbd: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel / faults: 1042 minor
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   m.abc.unten: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 203 minor
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 802 minor
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   droid.wallpaper: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 109 minor
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 44 minor
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   dhd_dpc: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):  +andisk.api.test: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):  +iTestFwService1: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90):  +sh: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-15 18:09:01.076: ERROR/ActivityManager(90): TOTAL: 40% = 23% user + 16% kernel + 0% iowait + 0% softirq
02-15 18:09:01.096: INFO/ActivityManager(90): Process com.abc.cm.core (pid 10548) has died.
```

Comment: Post the code for the Service.

Comment: Hi I think my answer to this question will interest you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229547/tips-for-debbugin-android-apps/5229669#5229669](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229547/tips-for-debbugin-android-apps/5229669#5229669)

Comment: My code is not really doing much IO or network operations. But thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Can you see the stack traces in /data/anr/traces.txt?  If two threads are locked up on monitors you'll be able to see it.  (Look for threads in the MONITOR state.)  If your device is rooted you can do "kill -3 <pid>" to get a stack trace in the log at any time.

Comment: Actually I find out that from ddms I can look at the list of threads for a selected process. I look for the threads in "monitor" state. I can even see call stack from ddms including files and line numbers. That is what I am using now.

Comment: The advantage of the "kill -3" output is that, for a thread in MONITOR state, it shows you the thread ID of the thread that it is waiting on.  If you have a lot of threads this can be a time-saver.

Comment: That is pretty neat. You should have posted this as an answer.

Comment: I agree.  I see several possible "answers" here and I suggest that they be fleshed-out a little bit and *become* formal "answers."

Answer (score 2):

Fixing deadlocks on any platform is hard.  The only way I know on Android is to add some logging statements (e.g., with `Log.d`) before and after each lock/unlock/otherExpensiveFunction.

Comment: That was my plan for tomorrow morning. I guess I don't have much options left.