# How to detect deadlocks programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, deadlock, detection

I know and used the resource available [here](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/detect-deadlocked-threads-using-threadmxbean-class-java/) to detect deadlocks programmatically in Java.

```
  ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

    long ids[] = bean.findMonitorDeadlockedThreads();

    if(ids != null)
    {
        ThreadInfo threadInfo[] = bean.getThreadInfo(ids);

        for (ThreadInfo threadInfo1 : threadInfo)
        {
            System.out.println(threadInfo1.getThreadId());    //Prints the ID of deadlocked thread

            System.out.println(threadInfo1.getThreadName());  //Prints the name of deadlocked thread

            System.out.println(threadInfo1.getLockName());    //Prints the string representation of an object for which thread has entered into deadlock.

            System.out.println(threadInfo1.getLockOwnerId());  //Prints the ID of thread which currently owns the object lock

            System.out.println(threadInfo1.getLockOwnerName());  //Prints name of the thread which currently owns the object lock.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No Deadlocked Threads");
    }
```

The code above determines and prints the deadlocked thread and related information. I tried the same in Android Studio and found that android doesn't support this. Is there an equivalent to that in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ThreadMXBean is not part of Android Framework. This question is already present here [Android finding a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320418/android-finding-a-deadlock)

Comment: So, there's no easy way! Thanks man! I googled a lot, but couldn't find any solution to this, now I know why.

Comment: The link you provided does not contain information about how to find deadlocks in Android programmatically.